# Filter Related product account current product category in Admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin, related-products

I want to filter related product collections by the current product category. I mean I want to show only current product category products in the related product grid in the admin side.
[image]

Is there any way where we can pass category id or filter related product collections?

Comment: You can manage product collection from  vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Related.php

Comment: how can I get the current product id in this file

Comment: there is a function getProduct() which gets current product so you can get $this->getProduct()->getId();